# Hover and Active only when not disabled

Tags: css

I use **hover**, **active** and **disabled** to style Buttons.

But the problem is when the button is disabled the hover and active styles still applies.

How to apply hover and active only on enabled buttons?

Answer (score 541, accepted):

You can use [:enabled](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#UIstates) pseudo-class, but *notice `IE<9` does not support it*:

```css
button:hover:enabled{
    /*your styles*/
}
button:active:enabled{
    /*your styles*/
}
```

Comment: There's also the `:not()` selector, but then again, it's only supported since IE9 as well. See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:not

Comment: `button:hover:enabled` didn't seem to work in my case. Using IE9 emulation under IE11.

Comment: @jnns thanks. Using this worked for me: button:hover:not([disabled])

Answer (score 134):

```
.button:active:hover:not([disabled]) {
    /*your styles*/
}
```

You can try this..

Comment: This is a good solution for when you want the "hover disabled" state to look identical to the "non-hovered disabled" state.

Comment: I <3 this solution.  allows me to have the following:

<button class="button">hovers</button> and
<button class="button no-hover>doesn't hover</button> 

by just using :not(.no-hover)

Comment: life saver 
for folks who using scss 

`.button {
 font-weight: 600 !important;
 width: 186px;
 height:46px;
 font-size: 16px !important;
 line-height: 144% !important;
 letter-spacing: -0.02em !important;
 opacity: 1;
 &:disabled,
 &.disabled{
  color:#fff;
  border-color: #a0a0a0;
  background-color: #a0a0a0;
 }
 &:disabled:hover,
 &:disabled:focus,
 &.disabled:hover,
 &.disabled:focus {
  color:#fff;
  border-color: #a0a0a0;
  background-color: #a0a0a0;
 }
 &:hover:not([disabled]) {
  opacity: v.$hoverOpacity;
 }
 }`

Comment: You can xplain active?

Answer (score 46):

Why not using attribute "disabled" in css. This must works on all browsers.

```
button[disabled]:hover {
    background: red;
}
button:hover {
    background: lime;
}
```

Comment: Cover all the disabled states by selecting them all in one line:
`.button[disabled], .button[disabled]:hover, .button[disabled]:focus, .button[disabled]:active {}`

Answer (score 32):

If you are using `LESS` or `Sass`,  You can try this:

```
.btn {
  &[disabled] {
    opacity: 0.6;
  }
  &:hover, &:active {
    &:not([disabled]) {
      background-color: darken($orange, 15);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: This is a good solution in SASS since the hover effect will get processed for a disabled button unless you wrap it in not block.

Answer (score 25):

Use the lightest touch: overriding via rule order.

```
.btn {
  /* base styles */
}

.btn:hover {
  color: red;
}

.btn:active {
  color: green;
}

.btn:disabled {
  color: #aaa;
}
```

The trick is the order -- apply all the non-disabled states first, makes sure they all have the same specificity, and do disabled last, with the same specificity.

This won't work for a "disabled" class added to links, or non-interactive elements, which don't have the `disabled` property.

(Edited to remove higher-specificity rules, and messing with `pointer-events`)

Answer (score 18):

In sass (scss):

```
 button {
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 4px;

  &:disabled{
    opacity: 0.4;

    &:hover{
      opacity: 0.4;  //this is what you want
    }
  }

  &:hover{
    opacity: 0.9;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I was too searching for it when I got one of the simplest methods.

For Pure CSS:

```
.button {
  background-color: #222222;
  color: #ffffff;
}

.button:hover {
  background-color: #111111;
}

.button:active {
  background-color: #000000;
}

.button:disabled {
  opacity: 0.5;
}

.button:disabled:hover {
  /*To see no effect except the disabled ones, resets the effects of hover to default of button*/
  background-color: #222222;
  color: #ffffff;
}
```

For SCSS:

```
.button{
  background-color: #222222;
  color: ffffff;
  &:hover{
    background: #111111;
  }
  &:active{
    background: #000000;
  }
  &:disabled{
    opacity: 0.5;
    &:hover{
      /*To see no effect except the disabled ones, resets the effects of hover to default of button*/
      background-color: #222222;
      color: #ffffff;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

One way is to add a partcular class while disabling buttons and overriding the hover and active states for that class in css. Or removing a class when disabling and specifying the hover and active pseudo properties on that class only in css. Either way, it likely cannot be done purely with css, you'll need to use a bit of js.

Answer (score 1):

Options:

1. Add a selector for enabled state.

```css
button:enabled {
}
```

This requires the element actually have an enabled state. (Buttons do, a div would not.)

2. Negate a selector for disabled state.

```
button:not(:disabled) {
}
```

3. Disable point events.

```
button:disabled {
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

I like this last approach as it can be applied to many styles, and I have never found it to be a problem.

Answer (score 1):

```css
/* Styles for the disabled state */
.customButton:disabled,
.customButton[disabled] {
  border: 1px solid #999999;
  background-color: #cccccc;
  color: #666666;
  cursor: not-allowed; /* Optional: Show a "not-allowed" cursor for better visual feedback */
}

.customButton:disabled:hover,
.customButton[disabled]:hover {
  /* You can optionally add different styles for the disabled button when hovered */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I use the one below in my project.

```
.bg-brand-3 {
  background-color: black;
  &[type="button"]:enabled {
    &:hover {
      background-color: orange;
    }
    &:active {
      background-color: green;
    }
  }
  &[type="submit"] {
    // css
  }
}
```

The `:enable` has the same meaning as `:not(:disabled)`