# CSS Hover if Button is disabled

Tags: html, css

I'm playing a little bit with my GTK3-Theme on Ubuntu. When i move the Mouse over the scrollbar button the button is changed - but only if the Button is enabled. If the Button is disabled (because the Slider can't be moved in this direction) nothing happens when i move the mouse over the button.

I want to have the same style for enabled and disabled Buttons. This don't work:

```
scrollbar button:hover:disabled { <style> }
```

Comment: Can you add your HTML?

Comment: There is no HTML. This is not something i want to have in a HTML file. I want to change the look of my GTK-theme on linux. There i can use CSS.

Comment: This on line is all i need in the file. Thats the whole code.

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/11600687

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```css
button[disabled]:hover { /* styling goes here */ }
```

Comment: Don't work. It seems thats something that doesn't work with the GTK file. When i try this for enabled buttons with i have the same - no effect.

Comment: Could it be a CSS file or resource load order? For troubleshooting purposes, you could try using `!important` in the relevant stylings, then judge next step based on if that works or not (don't worry, I'm not suggesting it as a permanent solution).

Comment: you mean 'background-image: linear-gradient(to right, red, red) !important'? no effect.

is it at all possible to combine the pseudo classes :disabled and :hover?

Comment: You could try literally `button:disabled:hover`, though it may depend on how GTK sets the disabled attribute. You could try a few possibilities to see if any stick, literally trial and error, like `button[disabled="1"]:hover`, `button[disabled=1]:hover`, `button[disabled="True"]:hover`, `button[disabled="disabled"]:hover`

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this for all :

```css
scrollbar {
   my: style;
}
```

If you want for only disabled `<button>` with the given class :

```css
button.my-class:disabled {
   background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div>
   <button class="my-class" disabled>Disabled</button><br>
   <button class="my-class">Enable</button><br>
   <input class="my-class" type="text" disabled/><br>
   Text disabled not button
</div>
```

Comment: this changes the style of the whole scrollbar. Thats not what i want. I want to change the style of disabled buttons.

Comment: Is that what you want now ?

Comment: No. i don't want to change the whole scrollbar only the disabled buttons.

Comment: I don't change the scrollbar. And in your question you ask for disabled and enabled. Please be sure of what you want

Comment: now i understand what YOU mean. i dont want to disable the scrollbar. when i use buttons ("arrows") at the scrollbar and the slider is at the top then the button is "disabled". this means i can't move the slider anymore. I can move the slider with the button at the end of the scrollbar down. when the slider is at the bottom the down button is 'disabled'. when the slider is in the middle both are 'enabled' (can be used).

i can customize the background-color for the disabled button with 'scrollbar button:disabled' but not together with hover: 'scrollbar button:disabled:hover' doesn't work.